# Correct way to have calculated values in React.js

Tags: javascript, data-binding, reactjs, calculated-field

*Setup*

So basically I have 3 dimension fields (length, width and height) that are backed by state. I want to keep the state in inches but allow the user to switch the units on the display at will. Currently I'm only supporting inches and feet so I have a "dimension_unit" state that stores the currently displayed units and display_dimensions_multiplier that stores 1.0  for inches and 1.0/12.0 for feet (both are in state). I have everything working exactly as I want except for one thing.

*Problem*

All values I've tried have worked except when you try to use a decimal. Basically, in the background it's running throw the multiplier to get saved in state on change and then multiplies back in the value for the field which basically erases the trailing "." as you type so say you were trying to type 4.5, what you would actually get in the field as you typed is 45. But if you type 45 and then move the cursor between the 4 and 5 add the . you'll end up with 4.5...

*My idea*

The way I was thinking about solving it was basically have a state variable for the display_length and then have the regular length state as well then have the display_length stay the same unless they change units and have the length calculated and stored on change and then just persist that... and the same for height and width... but that seems very un-react-ive so what is the react-ive way of doing this? Or is that it?

Happy to post example code if needed, but there is a good bit of code for any component so... yeah... hopefully just the explanation is enough.

## Edit1

Basic before fiddle: [before](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/37742/)

This is my idea I'm curious about: [after](https://jsfiddle.net/94e9vaxa/4/)

The main difference being:

```
_handleChange: function(ev){
  ev.stopPropagation()
  ev.preventDefault()
  var key = ev.target.name;
  var value = ev.target.value;
  var indims = this.state.input_dimensions;
  indims[key] = value;
  this.setState({input_dimensions: indims});
  value = (value / this.state.display_dimensions_multiplier);
  var dims = this.state.dimensions;
  dims[key] = value;
  this.setState({dimensions: dims});
},
```

Comment: Can you get something working in a Fiddle? that would help, I get what you're problem is, but not sure about your proposed fix. PS google 'react base fiddle' for a nice starting point

Comment: Will take bit to stripe down and get the before and after done, but I'll get it up and posted as soon as I can.

Comment: No need if the answer below suits you!

Comment: Added both. Curious to hear thoughts! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution is the right idea. A few similar ideas:

- Only update your stored value when the input is committed (for example `onBlur` instead of `onChange`). You can apply generic realtime input validation to make sure it's a valid number.
- Like you say use a separate "display" state (I would consider this an "input state") and when the component updates with the new stored value, only update the input state if it differs (when converted to the same units). This way you don't need to persist or worry about the "input state" outside the input components.
- When the input has focus, don't update the input state when the stored value changes. When the input does not have focus or blurs, update the input state to the stored value.

I don't know that any of these solutions or the one you proposed is more "Reacty" than the others. I think it's really up to you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I added a couple of fiddles. Please let me know what you think!